# Magento 2.3 Natural Sort Order for Numeric Attributes / Sort Order Wrong

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, sorting, product-sorting

I have a custom attribute (text field) - let's call it "size". It contains numeric values like 1,2,3,10,20,30. Products are sorted by this attribute on the category page.

Expected sort order:

> 1,2,3,10,20,30

Actual sort order:

> 1,10,2,20,3,30

I found this general answer which describes a general solution (not Magento related):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly

There seems to be a solution for Magento 1.9:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260419/magento-sort-attribute-by-decimal-not-alphanumerically

So here is my question:
**How can I achieve a natural sort order for attributes that contain numbers in Magento 2 on the category page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if you don't specify it in the attribute, text attributes allow different types of characters:

Since strings are allowed, Magento's sort query is as follows:

```
ORDER BY custom_order ASC, `e`.`entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 12;
```

And the sort order of this would be: **1,10,2,20,3,30**

On the other hand, if we indicate in the attribute configuration:

**Advanced Attribute Properties->Input Validation for Store Owner:** Integer number
[image]

The sorting query would automatically be as follows:

```
ORDER BY CAST(custom_order AS SIGNED) ASC, `e`.`entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 12;
```

And the sort order would be correct: **10,15,20,20,100**

**Conclusion:**
Change **Advanced Attribute Properties->Input Validation for Store Owner:** to "Integer number" in the attribute configuration.

Comment: This is the solution! It works! Never thought about this. Thank you! Please upvote this answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I was fighting with this for a whole day, heheheh

Comment: I have a similar problem, but this answer doesn't work in my case. It's the Product Name attribute that contains numbers. I've tried the different options but can't get this... product 10, product 20, product 6 to show on the category page as product 6, product 10, product 20. Is this possible in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

And why you are sorting via string in the first place?
I think that the most valid approach will be for you to change the column to int.

I done a quick check, and it looks like this is how things are done by MYSQL, so I think you can't do much about it, expect changing the column type.

To do that, you either must make an upgrade with upgradeSchema script or Declaratvie Schema.

**By the way!!!!**

I think you are trying to order your products on category page, right ?

**This is an OOTB functionality**

Just go to the

```
ADMIN -> Catalog -> Categories -> Your desired category -> Products in category tab
```

There you will have list of products, each of them has something like position, and this is responsible for positioning the element in the position search.

Comment: I'm using a string because Magento 2 does not allow to create attributes with numeric fields. Or am I missing something? Is it really a good practice to change the DB column type in Magento? I bet there must be some other way, right? Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: Kinda, it seems that it's not possible via magento admin panel.
It's possible via installation scripts.

Comment: Here is an example on how to do it.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically.html

Just change the type based on your needs.
I think that int will suit your problem.

Comment: @Stefan I updated the answer, I think it may interest, unless you looking for a full custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the slimier issue for custom collection and I have used the following code to fix this.

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->reset('order');
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order('CAST(`size` AS SIGNED) ASC');
```

Hope it'll solve the issue. Cheers!